# How would it be to generate these quantiles?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, quantile

I would like to be able to reproduce this legend with the d3 library, currently I have my own algorithm that does this operation for me, but I don't know how it would be with d3. For example for this data array [
24.17,
24.58,
24.82,
24.91,
26.25,
28.04,
29.67,
32.06,
32.08,
32.4,
32.53,
32.58,
32.94,
33.89,
34.15,
34.84,
35.39,
37.64,
40.75,
42.31,
46.89
]

The output of 3 serious quantiles

[image]

The output of 4 serious quantiles

[image]

The output of 5 serious quantiles

[image]

What I really need is a function that by passing the data array and the number of quantiles (3,4 or 5) the output is that of the image, taking into account that for example 3 is a minimum, maximum and a value between minimum and maximum, in reality they are not 3 quantiles, they would be 2, this procedure would be the same for 4 or 5, and these would be the colors that would be in the range colorbase: rgb(231, 25, 32)colorLimit: rgb(245, 163, 166)

**Subsequent remarks, following Mgraham's response**

Mgraham, I like your proposal and it's on the right track, however after checking with my data array (the one I put above) it doesn't seem to give the expected results, I think it's due to a precision issue, if you look closely In the examples I put above (in the images) you can see that for the matrix this would expect this >32.15% 32.06% / 34.15% <32.06% however I get this other >31.26% 33.98% / 31.26% <33.98% . As I said, trying to perfectly reproduce the legends of the image, and although it seems that I am close thanks to the proposal that they have made me.

**Code without d3(I even doubt it's totally fine)**

```
export const calcularCuantiles = (data, numQuantiles) => {
  data.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  var n = data.length;
  var quantiles = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < numQuantiles; i++) {
    quantiles.push(Math.ceil(i * (n - 1) / numQuantiles)); // Redondeo hacia arriba
  }
  // Agregar el último índice, que es n - 1
  quantiles.push(n - 1);
  var quantileValues = quantiles.map(q => d3.quantile(data, q / (n - 1)));
  // Eliminar el último elemento del array (repetido en la última iteración)
  quantileValues.pop();
  // Ordenar los cuantiles de mayor a menor
  quantileValues.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  return quantileValues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather to create a linear scale of colors like this:

```
var data =  [ 24.17, 24.58, 24.82, 24.91, 26.25, 28.04, 29.67, 32.06, 32.08, 32.4, 32.53, 32.58, 32.94, 33.89, 34.15, 34.84, 35.39, 37.64, 40.75, 42.31, 46.89 ]
var minValue = d3.min(data)
var maxValue = d3.max(data)
var minColor = "rgb(231, 25, 32)"
var maxColor = "rgb(245, 163, 166)"
const colorScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([maxValue,minValue])
    .range([maxColor,minColor])
// then use this color scale to get colors for your legend
console.log(colorScale(data[5])) // output: "rgb(233, 49, 55)"
```

Comment: First of all, thanks Alireza Balaei for answering, what I really need is to create an array of objects, where each object has two attributes, one with the quantile (quantile value) and the second attribute called color (this will have its corresponding color ), in this way I can share this array of objects in the legend to paint the value of the quantile and its corresponding color and use it in the deckgl layer to compare the colorvalue of the feature with that of the quantile to paint the feature with the color that it gives it. correspond

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to make the number of colours you require (according to the number of quantiles), and then feed them as input along with your data into a d3 quantileScale

From there you can get the cutoff values and start making your legend. Later, use the quantile scale to generate the colours for each individual datum as necessary

PS I should also point out there is a d3 legend library that will do this stuff with less work on your part, but hasn't been maintained to the latest d3 versions (https://github.com/susielu/d3-legend). If you're on d3 v5 or less it'll be worth a look.

```js
// Make a colour scale between 2 colours and pick X colours evenly from it
var numberOfQuantiles = 4;
var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear([0, numberOfQuantiles - 1], ['red', 'blue']);
var colors = d3.range(numberOfQuantiles).map((quantile, index) => {
  return colorScale(index);
});

// use those colours as input to the quantile scale along with your data
var data = [4, 5, 10, 16, 23, 35, 128, 56, 100, 56, 23, 14, 45, 67, 12];
var qs = d3.scaleQuantile()
  .domain(data)
  .range(colors);

// q has the quintile cutoff values in (1 less then the number of quantiles / colours)
var q = qs.quantiles();

// make a string, you can do a better job here
// thing to remember is the first and last only have one value to show
var s = '';
q.forEach((cutoff, i) => {
  s += "<span style='background: " + colors[i] + "'></span>";
  s += (i > 0) ? q[i - 1] + "-" : "<";
  s += cutoff; // cutoff = q[i]
})
// Last colour
s += "<span style='background: " + colors[colors.length - 1] + "'></span>&gt;" + q[q.length - 1];

d3.select("#output2").html(s);
```

```css
#output2>span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='output2'>
</div>
```

Comment: Mgraham just updated the question, please watch my progress, thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like d3.quantile sets the cutoffs in between data points rather than on them, and it does it such that the start/end quantiles are given "twice" their share of the gap as the internal quantiles (presumably as the internal quantiles will have 'padding' at both ends)

If you wanted the actual data point figures you'd need to find the value in your sorted data higher than the cutoff under consideration - 
index = d3.bisect(data, cutoff)
value = data[index]

Comment: I updated the post with my code, that's the closest I've been (without using d3), but it doesn't work for me, I hope your help Mgraham :)